# Using Singleton to create single MySQLi Connection and using it across multiple objects?

Tags: php, oop, singleton, mysqli

Goodmorning everybody!

I'm not completely new to PHP as in self but still kinda new when it comes to OO with PHP5. Now, I thought about this tiny project where I wanted to use HTML5 and some OO PHP. It's supposed to be a horizontally scrollable timeline one day.

Therefore I created a class **Timeline**. This is my main object. Among other methods, one method (*$timeline->createYearString();*) is to create my string of years. I implemented another class **Year** which the method *createYearString();* calls X number of times in order to create HTML output of my years.

In order to fill my years with facts, I need a database connection. Being new to the oop-approach towards mysql connections I search around and found Atli's comment (http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/81496-connection-to-the-mysql-using-oop/page__view__findpost__p__1038512) about a mysqli singleton. I implemented it and tried using it in object of class *Year*. Funny thing, $dbLink gets returned for the first object but not the second one which is created instantly exactly the way the first one was. *$this->db* suddenly returns NULL in the second year and therefore I get a non-object FATAL error from PHP

See my three classes below. What am I missing?

```
class Year {
 private $year;
 private $db;

 function __construct($year) {
  $this->year=$year;
  $this->db=MyDB::Get();
 }

 function createHTML($last='') {
  $out=" <div class=\"year_outer".(($last) ? ' last_year' : '')."\" id=\"y".$this->year."\">
     <div class=\"year_inner\">
      <div class=\"year_above\">
       <span class=\"yearnr\">".$this->year."</span>
      </div>
      <div class=\"year_below\"></div>
     </div>
     <div class=\"months_wrapper\">\n";
  if(!$last) {
   for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
    $fDoM = mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,$this->year);            // $fDoM = first Day of Month
    $lDoM = mktime(0,0,0,$i,date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,$this->year)),$this->year);  // $lDoM = last Day of Month
    $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tp_together");
    //echo date('d.m.Y',$fDoM)." bis ".date('d.m.Y',$lDoM)."\n";

    $out.= " <div class=\"month_outer_l\" id=\"".$this->year."-".$i."\">
        <div class=\"month_outer_s\">
         <div class=\"month_inner\"><span>".date("M",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,$this->year))."</span></div>
        </div>
       </div>\n";
    } 
  }  
  $out.= " </div>
    </div>\n";

  return $out;
 }
}

class Timeline {
 public $daysDating;
 public $startYear;
 public $endYear;
 public $numberOfYears;

 function __construct($start,$end='') {
  $this->startYear = $start;
  $this->endYear  = ($end=='') ? date("Y")+1 : $end;
  $this->daysDating = $this->calcDaysDating();
  $this->numberOfYears= $this->calcNumberOfYears();
 }

 function createYearString() {
  $x=new Year('2004');
  print $x->createHTML();
  $y=new Year('2005');
  print $y->createHTML();
  $z=new Year('2006');
  print $z->createHTML(true);

  // $j=$this->endYear;
  // for($i=$this->startYear; $i<=$j; $i++) {
  //  $x=new Year($i);
  //  ($i==$j) ?
  //   print $x->createHTML(true) :
  //   print $x->createHTML();
  // }
 }

 private function calcDaysDating() {
  $today=mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("y"));
  $day1=mktime(0,0,0,7,11,2006);

  return $today-$day1;
 }

 private function calcNumberOfYears() {
  return $this->endYear - $this->startYear +1;
 }

 function createHNavigation() {
  $x=1;
  $out='<ul>';
  for($i=$this->startYear; $i<=$this->endYear; $i++) {
   $out.="<li><a class=\"navBubble\" id=\"navBubble$i\" accesskey=\"$x\" href=\"#y$i\" title=\"Go to $i\"></a></li>\n";
   $x++;
  }
  $out.="</ul>";
  return $out;
 }
}

class MyDB {
 private static $dbLink;

 private function __construct() {}
 private function __clone() {}

 public static function Get() {
  if(!self::$dbLink) {
   self::$dbLink = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PWD, DB_NAME);
   if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    throw new Exception("Database connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
   }
   return self::$dbLink;
  }
 }
}
```

In case I didn't make my problem clear. $x resembles 2004 ($x=new Year('2004')) which works fine. But then the folling $y ($y=new Year('2005') returns the FATAL ERROR and $this->db returns NULL - WHY?

Thanks a lot, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Better use `'` to quote PHP strings so you can use `"` in your HTML. Escape orgies are awful if they can be avoided.

Comment: It is pointless to use Singletons in PHP. There is no shared application memory. The Singleton will only be a Singleton within it's own request. Three simultaneous requests will still create three instances. If you want to control the number of connections to your database, [configure the appropriate mysqli values](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php)

Comment: It's entirely not pointless, which you discover as soon as you start dealing with transactions.

Comment: Sure. As you know, when working with transactions you need to use the same connection for all your queries. If your queries are split among many functions, you need a way to access MySQLi connection object in everyone of them. You can make the object global, you can pass it as an argument, or you can use Singleton. Each of these methods has it's pros and cons. I prefer Singleton.

Comment: Right tools for the right job. In my work I depend heavily on MySQL specific features, so being dependent on this singleton doesn't relly matter all that much. It has one advantage over global object in that it cannot be silently overwritten. Dependency injection? Sure - as long as you can substitute MySQLi object with other object with same interface... hmmm... know any?

Comment: Well.. maybe I'm just not experienced enough in DI (and I'm first to admit that), to see how would it be useful in case where there are no candidate classes that could be used instead of MySQLi. Perhaps when working with multiple database connection within one request...
As far as depending on MySQL features go: I did not say it requires a singleton. I said the application uses so much MySQL specific syntax, that for all practical means loosening a dependency on MySQLi in favor of some DB abstraction layer is pretty much useless. It is not a good design, makes unit testing a pain...

Comment: ...but that's what I'm stuck with for the time being. A Singleton being less than perfect way of acquiring db connection object is the least of my worries here.

Comment: I get it, but don't see the point. Decoupling this dependency would have sense, if there was ever a chance, that I might actually need to use another class in this place. I don't, and I won't need to do so.

Comment: I was writing a reply about how I don't see the reason to mock a database connection, when all of sudden I saw the possible use for that. If I was testing if a method runs `$mysqli->query()` with `$expected` arguments that would be really useful indeed! As it is now, I use PhpUnit's database testing capabilities to test compare contents of tables before and after execution. I must think about it more! :)

Comment: Lol.. tell me about testing static methods... :D I could actually make the Singleton mockable in at least two ways (both of them ugly). I just need to find out, if I need this kind of tests.

Comment: In general yes. In reality we want something that works fairly well by yesterday :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static function Get() {
  if(!self::$dbLink) {
  self::$dbLink = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PWD, DB_NAME);
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   throw new Exception("Database connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  //was here
  }
   return self::$dbLink; //should be here
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your MyDB::Get function does not return self::$dbLink in the case where it already is set.

return in original:

```
public static function Get() {
    if(!self::$dbLink) {
        self::$dbLink = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PWD, DB_NAME);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            throw new Exception("Database connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        return self::$dbLink;
     }
}
```

return so that it works:

```
public static function Get() {
    if(!self::$dbLink) {
        self::$dbLink = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PWD, DB_NAME);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            throw new Exception("Database connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
        }
     }
     return self::$dbLink;
}
```

(PS, using more than a single character for an indent would make this a lot easier to detect.)